# Why don`t save the imageView in Activity that is loaded from gallery, when exit or tap on back?

Tags: android, imageview, exit, save-image

This is **MainActivity.java.** App includes of one activity with ImageView and Button. When tapping these button, the gallery must be open. After it you will check some image that is pasted in the ImageView. I couldn't save the image in activity when want to exit from app or tap back.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    super.onResume();
                }
        }
    }}
```

And this is **content_main.xml.** Here I created button and empty ImageView for paste the image from gallery. Please tell how can save image and text in activity.

Answer (score 0):

When Activity is closed it is destroyed. You should save the data somewhere and then restore it. For example in SharedPreferences. The simplest method is shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uriString = preferences.getString("MainPicture", null);

        if (uriString != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(uriString);
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("MainPicture", selectedImage.toString());
                editor.apply();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("MainPicture", selectedImage.toString());
                        editor.apply();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    super.onResume();
                }
        }
    }}
```